# Changing badge count in a TabLayout tab icon

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout with several tabs. One of them displays a number as a badge uppon the tab icon.
So when the tab hosting activity receive an event that tells it to update this notif count, I do this :

```
@Override
public void updateNotif(int notifCount) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.badge_layout_workspace_count, null);
    TextView badgeTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    badgeTv.setText(String.valueOf(notifCount));

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(PAGE_NOTIFS).setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), view.getDrawingCache()));
}
```

the layout `badge_layout_workspace_count` is simply a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` (the icon) and a `TextView` (the notif count)

This code does not cause crash but displays nothing.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

---

Ok, I just used setCustomView instead of setIcon, it works fine now :

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.badge_layout_workspace_count, null);
    TextView badgeTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    badgeTv.setText(String.valueOf(notifCount));
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(PAGE_NOTIFS).setCustomView(view);
```

Comment: Why are you inlating the view again? It is already there for you, just remove that line and call this.findViewById.

Comment: nope I don't have the view before, the tab icon is initialy set this way : mTabLayout.getTabAt(PAGE_NOTIFS).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_notif); , when there is no notif, there is no badge

Comment: Try debugging, put a breakpoint on setText line and deduce what goes wrong. It's kinda hard for us to do it like this :)

Comment: the setText goes well, but I don't see the icon at all, it's not just the badge that's missing

Comment: I feel that there is something about the DrawingCache that I don't understand

Comment: Don't use it if you don't understand it properly. Unfortunately, I don't know much about it either.

Comment: yeah I edited my question, there was a much more straight forward path to take